# Persisting state after app is killed and updating data from a background service

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, redux, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have made a React Native app that detects BLE devices when the app is in foreground/app is killed or in background using a foreground service and iOS provides CLLocationManager which does that for you.

As soon as a BLE device is detected I make a API call using an action on the React Native side, and get data according to venue and update the redux store variable. It works when the app is in foreground, but once the app is in killed state, the redux store won't be able to update the variables.

So in Essence if the BLE device is detected when the app is killed, the API call works using action, but the reducer variable is not updated, so when I open the app I cannot see the new data.

I tried using AsyncStorage can store only key value pairs, and I think maybe using AsyncStorage heavily could introduce problems? Correct me If I'm wrong.

The frequency of detecting BLE devices is quite high these days so I think it would be a frequent operation of updating data I need to perform.

Comment: Does the reducer persist?

Comment: @10101010 I dont think so

Comment: i am also facing the same problem, i found out it will be better if we use a database to store them locally on phone - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569936/database-for-storing-data-after-app-is-killed-in-react-native