# Database for storing data after app is killed in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, realm

I am making a React native app, with native services to scan for devices nearby. It works fine when the app is in foreground, but when the app is killed and the service detects a device, it wakes up the React Native part of app by headless JS and makes an API call using redux action, 
but it cannot store the data received from API call in reducer data.

I can't user AsyncStorage as the data is big and a JSON. How do I persist this data so that when the app is started, the users can see the data derived earlier from the API call?

Comment: You can use other storage such as realm(https://github.com/realm/realm-js) or react-native-sqlite-storage to save the big data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use firebase for data storage as it is simple to integrate with React-native. 
Here's the link to get started-

> https://firebase.google.com/

Or Meteor Js is one of the other options you have.

> https://www.meteor.com/

Edit::

If you want to use local storage then use the AsyncStorage. Here's the link to the docs -

> https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/asyncstorage/#__next

Comment: I need a local storage

Comment: I've tried AsyncStorage but I don't know if it has huge limit or can store objects not just key value pairs. Also does it have high read/write capacity

Comment: Yes, it has read/write capacity. You can use methods like getItem or setItem. There are methods like multiGet and multiSet for multiple data. As for the limit I don't have a proper idea about that but as far as i know it has a pretty decent higher bound.

Comment: SQLite Maybe an option?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked you can able to make offline apps with your database stored locally using SQLite.

```
npm install --save react-native-sqlite-storage
```

You can better check this article for more info:

https://brucelefebvre.com/blog/2018/11/06/react-native-offline-first-db-with-sqlite/